# Show that a set of linear maps that are not surjective, is not a subspace of all linear maps from $V$ to $W$

Tags: linear-algebra

"Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional with $\dim V \ge \dim W \ge 2$.
Show that $U=\{T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W): T $ is not surjective $\}$ is not a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$. "

( $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ is the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $W$ )

My attempt: If I assume that $U$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ then

Let $T,S \in U$, $v\in V$ and let $ T(v) = w_1,  S(v) = w_2 $

$$(T+S)(v)=T(v)+S(v) = w_1 + w_2 \longrightarrow T + S \in U$$
But this cannot be true because $w_1 \in  \operatorname{range}(T)$ and $w_2 \in  \operatorname{range}(S)$:
$$  \operatorname{range}(T) \neq  \operatorname{range}(S)$$

$T+S\notin U$, $U$ is not a subspace.

Is this proof correct?

My second attempt:If I assume that $U$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ then

Let $T,S \in U$, $v\in V$ and let $ T(v) = w_1,  S(v) = w_2 $

$$(S+T)(v)=S(v)+T(v)=w_1+w_2$$
$w_1 \in \operatorname{range}(T)$ and $w_2 \in \operatorname{range}(S)$

We know that the range of any linear map $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ is a subspace of $W$. So in this case, $\operatorname{range}(T)$ and $\operatorname{range}(S)$ are subspaces of W. This means that
$$\operatorname{span}(\operatorname{range}(T))=\operatorname{span}(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_m)$$
$$\operatorname{span}(\operatorname{range}(S))=\operatorname{span}(u_{m+1},u_{m+2},\dots,u_n)$$
$u_j \in W, j=1,2,\dots,n$

$w_1$ and $w_2$ can be expressed as linear combinations
$$ w_1 = k_1u_1 + k_2u_2 + \dots + k_mu_m$$ 
$$ w_2 = k_{m+1}u_{m+1} + k_{m+2}u_{m+2} + \dots + k_nu_n$$

Because $u_1,u_2,\dots, u_m $ is a basis of $ \operatorname{range}(T)$, there exists a unique linear map such that
$$T(v_j) = u_j$$ $v_j \in V, u_j \in W, j=1,2\dots,m$

Likewise, because $u_{m+1},u_{m+2},\dots,u_{n}$ is a basis of $\operatorname{range}(S)$, there exists a unique linear map such that
$$S(v_j) = u_j $$ $v_j \in V, u_j \in W, j=m+1,m+2,\dots, n$

This means that there are no $v_j \in V$ such that
$$ T(v_j) = S(v_j) $$
If there would exist $T,S \in U$ where $ T(v_j) = S(v_j)$ then
$$k_1u_1 + k_2u_2 + \dots + k_mu_m=w_2 = k_{m+1}u_{m+1} + k_{m+2}u_{m+2} + \dots + k_nu_n$$

$$\operatorname{range}(T) = \operatorname{range}(S) $$
But this is not the case. Therefore
$$ \operatorname{range}(T) \ne \operatorname{range}(S) $$

Because $\operatorname{range}(T) \ne \operatorname{range}(S)$, there exists $w_j \in \operatorname{range}(T),  w_j \notin \operatorname{range}(S) $. Let $j=1$. Now we have

$$ w_1 \in \operatorname{range}(T), w_1 \notin \operatorname{range}(S) $$
$w_2$ can either exist both in $\operatorname{range}(S)$ and $\operatorname{range}(T)$ or only in $\operatorname{range}(S)$. We test both alternatives and see the result.

Let $w_2 \in \operatorname{range}(S), w_2 \in \operatorname{range}(T)$

$$w_1+w_2 \in \operatorname{range}(T)$$
$$w_1+w_2 \notin \operatorname{range}(S)$$
This means that the range of T is closed under addition but the range of S is not closed under addition. $\operatorname{range}(S)$ can therefore not be a subspace of W. That means that $S \notin \mathcal{L}(V, W)$.

If  $U=\{T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W): T $ is surjective $\}$, then $\operatorname{range}(T) = \operatorname{range}(S) = W$. But in this case $\operatorname{range}(T) \ne \operatorname{range}(S) \ne W$

Attempt 3:
We know that $$\operatorname{dim}(V) \ge \operatorname{dim}(W) \ge 2$$ We know that
$U=\{T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W): T $ is not surjective $\}$.

Let $T \in U$. $T$ is not surjective, which implies that 
$$ \operatorname{range}(T) \ne W$$
But because $ T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W) $, $\operatorname{range}(T)$ is a subspace of $W$. Let $w_1, w_2, w_3, ... , w_n$ span $\operatorname{range}(T)$.
$$\operatorname{span}(\operatorname{range}(T)) = \operatorname{span}(w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n)$$
Now because $\operatorname{range}(T)$ is a subspace of $W$. $w_1, w_2,\dots, w_n$ can be expanded to span $W$.
$$ \operatorname{span}(W) = \operatorname{span}(w_1, w_2, \dots , w_n, w_{n+1}, w_{n+2}, \dots , w_{m}) $$
This implies that $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{range}(T)) < \operatorname{dim}(W)$, which means that
$$ \operatorname{dim}(V) > \operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{range}(T)) \ge 2 $$
We can check if $U$ is injective by checking if $ \operatorname{null}(T) = \{ 0 \} $. In order for that to be true then
$T(u) = T(v), u = v, u,v \in V$.

Let
$$ \operatorname{span}(w_1, w_2, \dots , w_m) = \operatorname{span}(Tv_1, Tv_2, \dots , Tv_m), Tv_j = w_j, j=1,2\dots,m, v_j \in V, w_j \in W $$
This means that
$$ T(v) = k_1w_1 + k_2w_2 + \dots + k_nw_n + k_{n+1}w_{n+1} + \dots + k_mw_m = k_1Tv_1 + k_2Tv_2 + \dots + k_nTv_n + k_{n+1}Tv_{n+1} + \dots + k_mTv_m $$

But we know that $T(v) \in \operatorname{range}(T) $ and because of that
$$ T(v) = k_1w_1 + k_2w_2 + \dots + k_nw_n = k_1 = k_1Tv_1 + k_2Tv_2 + \dots + k_nTv_n$$

This means that 
$$k_1Tv_1 + k_2Tv_2 + \dots + k_nTv_n = k_1Tv_1 + k_2Tv_2 + \dots + k_nTv_n + k_{n+1}Tv_{n+1} + \dots + k_mTv_m  $$
$$ k_{n+1}Tv_{n+1} + \dots + k_mTv_m = 0 $$
$$T(k_{n+1}v_{n+1}) + \dots + T(k_mv_m) = 0 $$
$$T(k_{n+1}v_{n+1} + \dots + k_mv_m ) = 0$$
Which implies that
$$ k_{n+1}v_{n+1} + \dots + k_mv_m \in \operatorname{null}(T)$$
This means that $\operatorname{null}(T) \ne \{0\} $ which means that T is not injective. So for all $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$, $T$ is not injective.

Now, let $T,S \in \mathcal{L}(V, W) $ and $u,v \in V$ such that
$T(v) = T(u), u \ne v $
$$ (T+S)(v) = T(v) + S(v) = T(u) + S(v) \ne (T+S)(v) $$

Comment: Why does it matter that the ranges are different?  Why can you conclude the sum isn't in $U$?

Comment: What makes you think that the ranges are different?

Comment: Hint: The set is not closed.  Construct a surjective map from elements of $U$.  Hint: Use dual vectors to a basis.

Comment: @MichaelBurr My thought was, if it is true that the ranges are different, then I can assume that the range of T is a set vectors in W (t1, t2, t3, ..., t_n) and the range of S is a set of vectors in W (s1, s2, s3, ..., s_n).In order for U to be closed under addition then we can assume that there is a v in V that when you take (T+S)(v) = T(v) + S(v) = w_1 + w_2, w_1 + w_2 can be either in the range of T, range of S or both of them. Assuming that it is only in range of T then there is an error because the range of S is then not only (s1, s2, ... , s_n) but instead (s1, s2, ..., s_n, v_j).

Comment: @MichaelBurr (cont.) so when you iterate it like that you will get that the range of T must be the range of S.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Because if U is a subspace, every T in U is uniquely mapping V to W. If T and S are in U, T(v) != S(v), v is in V.

Comment: General hint. When a problem begins "Show that ... is not true" you should probably start by looking for a relatively explicit single counterexample rather than a more abstract argument. You can see that strategy in the two answers.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you for the hint. There are many more of similar problems in the book i am reading so it might be easier now.

Comment: @E.Bob You're welcome. Life is a little trickier when the problem says "Prove or disprove ...". Then perhaps you start looking for a counterexample. If you can't find one you look for a proof. If you can't find one you go back to the search for a counterexample ... until you finally understand it all. The best kind of question.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have edited my answer. Would really help me if you or anyone (cannot tag more than one user) could check if that explanation is correct. The answer is similar to the first one, just that I have expanded it so you can know my thought process more detailed. The two answers were helpful but I cannot let go of the abstract answer of the question.

Comment: The updated answer is still not correct.    Some issues: The ranges could overlap (even if they’re not equal), so you can’t get distinct basis elements.  Also, these maps are not injective, so you can’t guarantee the uniqueness of the $v_j$’s.  Moreover, the range argument doesn’t work because closure doesn’t tell you anything when you’re adding something not in the range.  The condition on $U$ is non-surjectivity and you’ve never really used surjectivity in the entire answer (this hints at the fact that there’s something missing).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you very much for your response. I decided to re-think and I think I got it right now. Can you check the new edited answer(Attempt 3). Thank you once again. (I do not have a teacher, so your answers are really helping me a lot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a basis $v_1,...,v_m,...,v_n$ of $V$ and a basis $w_1,...,w_m$ of $W$. Consider the linear maps $Tv_i=w_i$, for $i=1,...,m-1$ and $Tv_i=0$, for $i\geq m$, while $Sv_m=w_m$ and $Sv_i=0$ for $i\neq m$. When you add them you get a surjective linear map.

Answer (score 3):

You want to find two linear transformations from $V \to W$ that are not surjective but their linear combination is surjective.

Suppose that $\dim V = \dim W = 2$ for now to see the main idea more clearly.

Consider $T$ and $S$ as maps from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ sending $(x,y) \to (x,0)$ and $(x,y) \to (0,y)$ respectively. None of these transformations are surjective on their own, yet $T+S$ is surjective.

Now, similarly generalize this argument to other cases where $\dim V \geq \dim W \geq 2$.